# AJAX JQuery request with XML response

Tags: ajax, xml, jquery

I've an AJAX call to a webservice from an external domain and I'm trying to manage the XML response, the AJAX call works because the objective it's to login on a Adobe Connect platform and it works. But it shows on browser console as the following error:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

That's the code of the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({ 
type : "GET", 
    url : URL, 
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(service_data) { 
    console.log("OK");
    console.log(service_data);
    },
    error : function(msg) {
    console.log("ERROR");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }
});
```

Thanks a million.

Comment: Could clarify your question?, I mean, your call works but with errors?

Comment: What does the original `XML` look like?

Comment: Exactly, It works because the objective it's to login and that works, but It throw the error I show above.

Comment: The original XML look like very simple, like this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results><status code="ok"/></results>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error do you get is because you are saying that you are expecting a jsonp and a xml is provided.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type : "GET", 
    url : URL, 
    dataType : "xml",
    success : function(service_data) { 
        console.log("OK");
        console.log(service_data);
    },
    error : function(msg) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }
});
```

I'd change the dataType

Comment: Thanks Lt but your answer doesn't work.
Actually the XML error has been solved, but the AJAX call doesn't work, the situation get worse.

Comment: Presumably, in that case, Adobe Connect is not telling the user's browser that your site has permission to fetch data from Adobe Connect with their (the user's) credentials.

Answer (score 3):

A colleage told me about two possibles solutions:

1 - CORS

2 - A proxy script.

I'll tell you if it work, I'm gonna try the fisrt one.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the datatype as 'jsonp' but you are getting xml as the result.  Try changing the datatype to 'xml'.  More information can be found at  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ but the relevant bits are:

> "xml": Returns a XML document that can be processed via jQuery.

.

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.